# how to use angularjs multidropdown for changing data

Tags: angularjs

I have a dropdown that fetch user data from an api:-

```
<label>User List:</label>
   <select ng-options="a as a.userCode for a in users" ng-model="user">
   </select>
```

My directive Code:-

```
scope.getAllUsers = function(){
       scope.users = [];
   ApiServices.getAllUsers().then(function (response) {
       scope.users = response.data;//array of objects
     });
  }

  scope.getAllUsers();
```

I want to multiselect values from above dropdown. So I am thinking of using http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main 
but as per the examples I can only use for that defined array of objects in controller. Is there any way to use it for server data which can change anytime.

Comment: Well which directive are you talking about ? It seems like a controller code, not directive one

Comment: The above code is inside my directive. I didn't mention the unnecessary code.

Comment: Ok but where are you calling this directive in the html code ? I only see ngOptions and ngModel called

Comment: Its in my different html page called 'index.html' as element <users></users>

Comment: I am sorry I don't understand your problem, if you are not using the directive on this html page, you are either showing us the directive code for nothing or this html for nothing. Considering your question is about the dropdown, I don't know what this directive code is doing there.

Can you make a jsfiddle of your problem ? I think it would be more clear

Answer (score 0):

For this situation create service for fetching data from server and use callback function to return data after success response.